# Can't address imported Angular Component's Selector in Cypress Component Test

Tags: angular, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I import an angular component from a library. It has the selector `<imported-component-group>`.

I place this component inside my local angular component.

When writing a cypress component test, I can't access this imported component by its component name, but only by a class name I assign to it.

This is how I place the imported component inside my local component:

```
<imported-component-group *ngIf="showImportedComponent(condition$) | async" class="importedComponentGroup">
   
   <imported-component>
   ...
   </imported-component>
   
   <imported-component>
   ...
   </imported-component>
   
</imported-component-group>
```

And from my component test, I try to address it like so:

```
cy.get('imported-component-group')
```

and so:

```
cy.get('<imported-component-group>')
```

Both approaches do not find my component, but it works, if I address it via the class instead:

```
cy.get('.importedComponentGroup')
```

The `*ngIf` condition should not be the problem, otherwise `cy.get('.importedComponent')` would not find it either. Also, this component exists only once within the HTML code.

Since I only created the class for the component test, I would like to get rid of it and directly address the component by its tag name.

It would be great if anybody has an idea about what I am missing here.

Comment: You would want to look at the DOM and see if `<imported-component>` has been compiled away into other elements (`<divs>` etc). Generally Cypress has no trouble selecting custom tag names, but there might be something about that one that causes problems. Obviously you have given a dummy tag. What's the real one?

Comment: @LolaIchingbola Thank you for your comment – unfortunately, it is not possible to give the real name.
What could be considered is, that the tag contains an *ngIf statement (I'll add it in my question). But since addressing the class works, this should not make any difference.

Comment: maybe a typo in real case?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me, I think I have an explanation (not a "solution") based on a Cypress example.

Answer (score 5):

To illustrate looking at DOM tags, have a look at the Cypress sample [cypress-component-testing-apps
/angular-standalone/](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-component-testing-apps/tree/main/angular-standalone). (**Note** I needed to install `@angular-devkit/core` which is missing in the `package.json`)

If you look at the spec `app.component.cy.ts` which is for `AppComponent` which contains/uses `WelcomeComponent` (running only the first test), the DOM looks like this:

[image]

which shows the `WelcomeComponent` with tag `<app-welcome>`, and I can select on that tag by adding this line to the test:

```js
...
cy.get('app-welcome').should('contain', 'Welcome testuser')
```

But if I run the spec `welcome.component.cy.ts` (just the first test again), the DOM looks like this:

[image]

now there is no tag `<app-welcome>` available for Cypress to select on, it's just providing the raw HTML that the component template gives:

```html
<div class="max-w-screen-sm p-12 mx-auto bg-gray-50 rounded-md shadow-lg">
    <h1 class="test-2xl">Welcome {{ username }}</h1>
    <app-button (onClick)="onLogout.emit()">Log Out</app-button>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how comparable this example is when using and external lib component, but you can check the DOM in your own test.

You can't go by the source template, you will need to inspect the DOM via devtools.

Comment: This is a typical behavior for components created using `TestBed`. Component under the test will reside in `#rootN` element, not in selector tag. Note that `N` changes between tests.